# TypeScript: Type of property incompatible when assigning from generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following code: (also example code here https://codesandbox.io/s/hbtew?file=/src/index.ts)

```
enum Types {TEXT, DATE}

interface TextState {
  type: typeof Types.TEXT
}

interface DateState {
  type: typeof Types.DATE
}

type State = TextState | DateState;

interface GenericProps {
  state: State
}

interface InputProps<AnyState> {
  state: AnyState;
}

function TextInput(props: InputProps<TextState>) {
}

function DateInput(props: InputProps<DateState>) {
}

const props: GenericProps = {state: {type: Types.TEXT}};
/*
Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'TextState'.
  Type 'DateState' is not assignable to type 'TextState'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'Types.DATE' is not assignable to type 'Types.TEXT'
*/
TextInput(props);

const {state} = props;
/*
Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'TextState'.
  Type 'DateState' is not assignable to type 'TextState'
*/
TextInput({state: state});

/* OK */
TextInput({state: {type: Types.TEXT}});

/* OK */
DateInput({state: {type: Types.DATE}});
```

As you see calling `TextInput(props)` got an error. Could you please explain how it got that error and how would you fix the code so that calling `TextInput(props)` will not give an error? The aim is to be able to construct different `GenericProps`, only differ in `type` and can be passed to either `TextInput(props)` (if `props = {state: {type: Types.TEXT}}`) or `DateInput(props)` (if `props = {state: {type: Types.DATE}}`), thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you need to "help" Typescript understand that you've validated the props type,
because otherwise you might change the state type.

you can solve that by adding a `validateTextProps` function that looks like that:

```
function validateTextProps(props: GenericProps): props is InputProps<TextState> {
  return props.state.type === Types.TEXT;
}

const props: GenericProps = { state: { type: Types.TEXT } };
if(validateTextProps(props)){
  TextInput(props);
}
```

That way Typescript understands that the props are of correct type and will allow you to call TextInput(props).

Comment: Thank you. But that means I will have to create these boolean functions for every single type. Not really something nice, but if this is the only way, I will accept it. Could you please suggest also a way to use `switch` rather than `if`?